# Grep kata in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I've written a simple `grep` program as my first foray into Elixir. Could you please suggest some ways in which the code could make better use of the language?

```
defmodule Exgrep do

  def exgrep(path \\ ".", substring) do
    case File.ls(path) do
      {:ok, ls} ->
        Enum.map(ls, fn new_path -> exgrep Path.join(path, new_path), substring end)
      {:error, _} ->
        exgrep_file path, substring
    end
  end

  def exgrep_file(path, substring) do
    case File.open(path, [:read]) do
      {:ok, f} -> line_grep f, substring, path
      {:error, _} -> nil
    end
  end

  def line_grep(file, substring, path) do
    case IO.read(file, :line) do
      :eof -> nil
      line ->
        if (String.contains?(line, substring)) do
          IO.puts "LINE: #{String.trim(line)} IN: #{path}"
        end
        line_grep file, substring, path
    end
  end

end

Exgrep.exgrep ".", "par"
```

Output:

```
LINE: sparrow IN: ./animals/birds/city.txt
LINE: leopard IN: ./animals/other.txt
LINE: Exgrep.exgrep ".", "par" IN: ./exgrep.ex
[nil, [[nil], nil], nil, nil]
```